# Where does the configuration for routing rules come from on boot?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, rhel7, policy-routing

I am on RHEL7 with NetworkManager disabled and no additional legacy scripts installed.
Meaning, that I still use:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth0
```

I have a problem with the `rule-eth0` file. It loads nicely, and whenever I modify it and run `$ systemctl restart networking`, the new routing rules are getting picked up and are visible with `$ ip rule`. They also get picked up if I use the `ifup-routes`.

However, if I modify the `rule-eth0` file, the old rules that were there before dont get removed.  New ones get added though. I've tried running scripts in the `network-scripts` directory, they stay there unless I manually delete one after another.

I resorted to using:

```
$ ip rule flush
```

Which deleted all the rules, including the ones for the `main` and `default` table, meaning any SSH connection would get lost.

**MY CONFUSION**

If I delete all `rule` files and reboot the machine, I get my default routes back. By running `$ ip rules` is see:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32766   from all lookup main
32767   from all lookup default
```

**Question**
How do I get the same behavior without a reboot?

How do I get these default rules back after running `$ ip rule flush`, without rebooting the machine or specifying the rules manually one after another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules are the default rules set by the kernel without any userland assistance when it initializes the initial network stack (or a new network namespace).

Here's the [relevant kernel source excerpt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/fib_rules.c?h=v3.10.108#n287):

> ```
> static int fib_default_rules_init(struct fib_rules_ops *ops)
> {
>   int err;
>
>   err = fib_default_rule_add(ops, 0, RT_TABLE_LOCAL, 0);
>   if (err < 0)
>       return err;
>   err = fib_default_rule_add(ops, 0x7FFE, RT_TABLE_MAIN, 0);
>   if (err < 0)
>       return err;
>   err = fib_default_rule_add(ops, 0x7FFF, RT_TABLE_DEFAULT, 0);
>   if (err < 0)
>       return err;
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

0x7FFE = 32766
0x7FFF = 32767

etc.

To address the last question: have a script. There's even `ip rule save`/`ip rule restore` with very limited usefulness. You shouldn't run `ip rule flush` without some selector to limit its scope to an intended rules subset. Eg: `ip rule flush lookup 1000` will delete any entry (even partially) matching `lookup 1000`.

Comment: I see. So the solution to persistent configuration is to manually define local, main and default rules in the rule file. Then with the script, I have to flush all the rules and readd them from the rule file. Otherwise, how would I know what rules to flush (other people are playing with the machine, my job is to undo anything they do).